# Using Spring Framework's @Autowired for instantiating and injecting SUT (System Under Test) in the test fixture

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have seen developers using Spring's @Autowired feature making Spring framework responsible for instantiating and injecting SUT (System Under Test) or CUT (Class Under Test) in the test class or fixture. The following is the snippet showing @Autowired being used in the test fixture:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.ExpectedException;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;



interface BackingStore
{
    //Some methods
}


class Logger
{
    public Logger(BackingStore backingStore)
    {
        //Capture input parameter into member variables
    }

    public void Log(String message) 
    {
        //Some logic
    }
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:someconfig.xml" })
public class LoggerTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private Logger _logger;

    @Test
    @ExpectedException(NullPointerException)
    public void Log_WhenPassedNull_ShouldThrowException()
    {
        _logger.Log(null);
    }
}
```

All the dependencies (recursively) required by the SUT are specified as part of the Spring configuration XML file. I do not like this approach. I like all the test (unit or integration) to read like a story (I heard Kent Beck saying the same thing :)). I like instantiating SUT/CUT in the test case itself even though if it is complex. This gives a clear picture about the test case.

I have few concerns regarding @Autowired or any auto injection mechanism being used for injecting SUT in the test fixture:

1. It reduces test code readability. @Autowire appears like magic. Arrange of AAA (Arrange-Act-Assert) moves to XML file from test code.
2. It reduces test code maintainability. This is because of #2.
3. Could not effectively verify constructor of SUT/CUT throwing exception in exceptional cases. I am not 100% sure about this. I do not know if Spring framework has an answer for this.
4. It seems overkill for unit or integration tests.

I ask experts for 2 cents on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: @AHungerArtist: 'Mocking for unit tests' - what is the point you are making?

Answer (score 1):

It only reduces test code readability if you dont know where to look for the @Autowired objects. I would advise using SpringJunitTestRunner that defines the test application context at the top of the unit test class.

Using dependency injection in your test cases allows you to easily test with different objects.

E.g. If your code required a 3rd party service, you could use dependency injection (e.g. Autowiring a Spring bean) to inject a mocked service for your unit tests and the real service for the application.

So for this reason it definitley doesnt decrease the test code maintainability, as it is really encouraging loose coupling between the code youre testing and any external objects.

It *may* be overkill to inject all objects in such a way, but it is definitely not overkill for unit tests/integration tests in general.

Comment: Added ContextConfiguration annotation on top of LoggerTests class.

Comment: #1 - What about AAA structure of the test code? To my understanding, AAA is all about test code readability. #3 - How to test some behavior in constructor when SUT is instantiated and getting injected by the Spring framework?

Comment: Well your test could check that the object has been instantiated accurately. Or just create a test for testing constructor that creates a new object.

Comment: I think, you have not got the question right. Autowiring is not used in the production class. Please go through the example in the question. It is used only in the test fixture. I understand the benefits of dependency injection and inversion of control frameworks. But, I could not understand the benefit of it for injecting SUT in the test fixture.